# Loading Avro files from GCS into a partitioned BQ table

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, avro

I have 2 BQ environments: One in EU and one in US.
I need to migrate data from table `foo_EU` to `foo_US` (both tables have an identical schema).
BQ currently does not allow for direct cross-region migration, so one has to export the data to a cross-region-friendly staging area (such as GCS) and then load the data from there.

But I have a problem, that both of my tables are partitioned under the expression `DATE(some_timestamp_col)`

When I export from `foo_EU` to GCS as avro, `some_timestamp_col` is transformed as an avro long (which is intended behavior specified by the BQ docs)

And when I try to load the data from GCS to `foo_us`, BQ will naturally interpret the avro long as an `INT64` value, so I get an error saying

```
The field specified for DAY partitioning can only be of type TIMESTAMP, DATETIME or DATE. The type found is: INT64.
```

I've already tried to specify a partition expression manually in the load statement like so

```
LOAD DATA INTO `my-project.my_dataset.foo_US`
partition by date(timestamp_seconds(some_timestamp_col))
FROM FILES (
  format = 'avro',
  uris = ['gs://my-bucket/staging-area/*'])
```

but it instead throws an error saying

```
PARTITION BY expression must be _PARTITIONDATE, DATE(_PARTITIONTIME), DATE(<timestamp_column>), DATE(<datetime_column>), DATETIME_TRUNC(<datetime_column>, DAY/HOUR/MONTH/YEAR), a DATE column, TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(<timestamp_column>, DAY/HOUR/MONTH/YEAR), DATE_TRUNC(<date_column>, MONTH/YEAR), or RANGE_BUCKET(<int64_column>, GENERATE_ARRAY(<int64_value>, <int64_value>[, <int64_value>]))
```

I've tried several different partition expression. `Timestamp_seconds` seems to be the best to use since its the only one that actually takes an int64 and returns a timestamp.

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: What about BigQuery data transfer service?